# col and row spans in android table layout android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to make following layout in android but unable to make because i new to table layout and tried a lot to fix column spans and row spans.

[image]

This is what i had tried last, but the problem is the heading in first column, i want a row span of 2 but unable to do that so i put another blank row there.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fillable_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixed_column_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="Account"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="*">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_span="2"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Opening Balance"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_span="2"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Transaction During Period"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_span="2"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Closing Balance"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:background="#FFC7C7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Debit"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="#FBFFC7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Credit"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="#FFC7C7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Debit"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="#FBFFC7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Credit"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="#FFC7C7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Debit"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="#FBFFC7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Credit"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Data in all rows are dynamic except headings.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: "*[...] tried a lot to fix column spans and row spans*" - show what you have tried. As of right now, it looks like a code-writing request and that's not what StackOverflow is for. You need to show your effort first.

Comment: sorry for that @Fureeish